# limiting distribution of a function of joint normals

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Let $Z_n=(X_{1,n},X_{2,n})\sim N(\mu,\Sigma_n)$ where $\mu=(0,0)'$ and $$\Sigma_n=\begin{bmatrix}a^2+\frac1n & ab \\ab & b^2+\frac1n\end{bmatrix}$$
Then where does $Y_n=\alpha_1X_{1,n}^2+\alpha_2X_{2,n}^2$ converge to?

Primarily I wrote down the characteristic function of $Y_n$, say $\phi_n(t)$ and then let $n \to \infty$. Limit of $\phi_n$ turns out to be $(1-2it\delta)^{-1/2}$ with $\delta=\alpha_1a^2+\alpha_2b^2$, i.e. $Y_n\to\delta \chi_{(1)}^2$.

My question is that is there a more straightforward/easy/neat way to look at this problem?

Many thanks for any comments in advance.